# How to move the insertion cursor of a tkinter text widget to a certain index

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I want to move the [insertion cursor(caret)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation)(`|`) within the [tkinter text widget](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html), to a certain [text widget indice](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/text-index.html).

**USE CASE:**

I am making an autocomplete program wherein if I type one [single apostrophe(quotation mark)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark), the other one automatically is inserted into the text widget, which I got working all fine. But after, the second apostrophe is generated I want to bring the insertion cursor(caret), in the middle of the two apostrophes rather than at the end. Like so -:

One apostrophe typed(inside the tkinter text widget) -:

```
'[insertion cursor(caret)(|)]
```

The other one is auto-inserted pushing the insertion cursor(caret) to the end(The code till this part has been figured out by me successfully.) -:

```
''[insertion cursor(caret)(|)]
```

The insertion cursor(caret) shifts between the two apostrophes(The objective of this question.) -:

```
'[insertion cursor(caret)(|)]'
```

**NOTE:** These operations are all taking place within a [tkinter text widget](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html).

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Well you see how when we write there is a vertical line that appears at our current index thats called insertion cursor while what I wanna ask is that how can I move that insertion cursor using tkinter. Hope that simplifies it. Basically what I am doing may complicate it so yea basically this is the simplified question.

Comment: @Ahmed Mamdouh, I have tried editing the question to make it feel more clear. Thanks for pointing this out, it definitely will be of help to future visitors if the question's readability is at a good standard. Also sorry for the late edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You call the `mark_set` method, using "insert" as the name of the mark.

`the_widget.mark_set("insert", "4.0")` will set the insertion cursor at the start of the fourth line. You can use `the_widget.mark_set("insert", "insert-1c")` to move the cursor back one character.

Here is an example of one way for automatically inserting a closing parenthesis or bracket. In this example, the code inserts both the opening and closing character so it returns "break" to prevent the default behavior provided by the text widget.

```
import tkinter as tk

def autocomplete(widget, first, last):
    # insert the two characters at the insertion point
    widget.insert("insert", first + last)

    # move insertion cursor back one character
    widget.mark_set("insert", "insert-1c")

    # prevent the text widget from inserting the character that
    # triggered the event since we've already inserted it.
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()
text = tk.Text(root, wrap="word")
text.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

text.bind("(", lambda event: autocomplete(event.widget, "(", ")"))
text.bind("[", lambda event: autocomplete(event.widget, "[", "]"))

root.mainloop()
```